# How can I count the users with more than 1 Order?

Tags: mysql, count

I'm working on a MySQL database and I need to query the database and find out the users with more than one order. I tried using COUNT() but I cannot get it right. Can you please explain the correct way to do this?.

Here are my tables:

- User

  ```
  +-------------+----------+------------------+------------+
  | userID      | fName    | email            | phone      |
  +-------------+----------+------------------+------------+
  | adele012    | Adele    | aash@gmail.com   | 0123948498 |
  | ana022      | Anna     | ashow@gmail.com  | 0228374847 |
  | david2012   | David    | north@gmail.com  | 902849302  |
  | jefAlan     | Jeffery  | jefal@gmail.com  | 0338473837 |
  | josquein    | Joseph   | jquein@gmail,com | 0098374678 |
  | jweiz       | John     | jwei@gmail.com   | 3294783784 |
  | jwick123    | John     | jwik@gmail.com   | 0998398390 |
  | kenwipp     | Kenneth  | kwip@gmail.com   | 0112938394 |
  | mathCler    | Maththew | matc@gmail.com   | 0238927483 |
  | natalij2012 | Natalie  | nj@gmail.com     | 1129093210 |
  +-------------+----------+------------------+------------+
  ```
- Orders

  ```
  +---------+------------+-------------+-------------+
  | orderID | date       | User_userID | orderStatus |
  +---------+------------+-------------+-------------+
  |       1 | 2012-01-10 | david2012   | Delivered   |
  |       2 | 2012-01-15 | jweiz       | Delivered   |
  |       3 | 2013-08-15 | david2012   | Delivered   |
  |       4 | 2013-03-15 | natalij2012 | Delivered   |
  |       5 | 2014-03-04 | josquein    | Delivered   |
  |       6 | 2014-01-15 | jweiz       | Delivered   |
  |       7 | 2014-02-15 | josquein    | Delivered   |
  |       8 | 2015-10-12 | jwick123    | Delivered   |
  |       9 | 2015-02-20 | ana022      | Delivered   |
  |      10 | 2015-11-20 | kenwipp     | Processed   |
  +---------+------------+-------------+-------------+
  ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select user_userID, count(*) as orders_count from orders 
group by user_userID having orders_count > 1
```

if you want additional data from your users table, you can do:

```
select * from user where user_id in (
  select user_userID as orders_count from orders 
  group by user_userID having orders_count > 1
)
```

Comment: This is right on target. It could also be written as `select user_userID from orders group by user_userID having count(*) > 1`. Also, it will be beneficial to compare speed of `where exists` vs. `where user_id in` depending on OP's dataset size

Comment: I forgot to use GROUP BY in my initial query.
First one works fine. But when I try to get more info using the sub query
it fails with error 
   ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'user_ID' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery

Comment: This worked for me  
    SELECT * FROM User WHERE userID IN (
  SELECT User_userID as userID FROM Orders GROUP BY User_userID HAVING count(*) > 1
);